# Is there a way to avoid blank pages with page breaks using interop.word?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I've been assigned to make a C# application that generates a multi-page document. I've been using interop.word to generate my pages. While the page generation is OK, sometimes I get a wild blank page that I can't seem to get rid of during generation.

My pages vary in length; some have a page full of text and some have a quarter of the page filled with text. 
How can I make it so I don't get unwanted blank pages in my generated documents?

I've tried using the function below. All it does is insert a pagebreak.

```
    private void newPage(Word._Document doc)
    {
        doc.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
    }
```

An example of generating a new page is:

```
    else if (iter == "Bedrijfsinformatie")
    {
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph, 16, "Cambria", 0, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, true, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph1, 9, "Cambria", 1, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph2, 9, "Cambria", 1, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph3, 9, "Cambria", 1, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph4, 9, "Cambria", 1, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph5, 9, "Cambria", 1, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph6, 9, "Cambria", 1, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        createParagraphIntro(oDoc, oMissing, paragraph7, 9, "Cambria", 6, 0, Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, false, false, true);
        //newPage(oDoc);
    }
```

and the createParagraphIntro method:

```
private void createParagraphIntro(Word._Document oDoc, object oMissing, string paragraphcontent, int fontsize, string fontname, int SpaceAfter,int spaceBefore, Word.WdParagraphAlignment alignment, bool bold, bool header,bool insertparagraph)
    {
        Word.Paragraph oPara;
        oPara = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        object oStyleName = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1;
        object oStyleName1 = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal;
        // to set the heading
        if (header == true)
            oPara.Range.set_Style(ref oStyleName);
        else
            oPara.Range.set_Style(ref oStyleName1);
        // to make the text bold
        if (bold == true)
            oPara.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        else
            oPara.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
        oPara.Range.Text = paragraphcontent;
        oPara.Format.SpaceBefore = spaceBefore * 10;
        oPara.Format.SpaceAfter = SpaceAfter*10;    // spacing after paragraph.
        oPara.Range.Font.Size = fontsize;
        oPara.Range.Font.Name = fontname;
        oPara.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = alignment; 
        oPara.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    }
```

I expect my application to generate a word document without blank pages. This is not the case at the moment.

I hope anyone can help me with this problem.

Edit:
Don't mind the language, I'm dutch.

image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: Can you open generated document and investigate why there are blank pages? What is wrong? Is it extra page break (two in rows)? Is it empty paragraph with page break (try to add page break to non-empty one)?

Comment: I've double checked and I have no double page breaks. After each page is filled, I call a page break.

Comment: Again, why there are blank pages? How does content of such pages looks like? Open it in word, enable special characters, observe, look at previous page, look at following page, make a guess.. As a workaround you can [remove blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16710782/1997232) afterwards (think about it as post-processing).

Comment: I've added 2 images to the question. The first image represents the document, as you can see, the third page is empty and you can see a page break while I haven't in my code. The generation code is shown in image 2.

Comment: For page `Prijslijst` you don't add anything to the page (maybe you forgot?) and still calling `newPage()`. Why? Call `newPage()` only if you have content on page.

Comment: Yeah i just noticed it myself as well. The random blank page is gone after adding a paragraph and my document is structured properly. Sometimes my stupidity amazes me...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sinatr I've figured out my problem. I've forgot to add a paragraph during the generation of a new page resulting in an empty page. My own stupidity amazes me...